# rails mongoid3 and SEO URLs

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, seo, mongoid3

is there a good way to make "friendly_ids" for the mongoid3 gem?

*slugoid*  seems deprecated and *KEY* is not part of mongoid3 anymore.

Any answer will be very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm using **[mongoid-slugify](https://github.com/fxposter/mongoid-slugify)** you just provide a method to generate slug, for example :

```
def generate_slug
   self.name.parameterize
end
```

in that code i assume you have **name** field in your model